# Does the direction of coil winding impact the direction of induced voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

In Case 1) and Case 2) (see the image below) induced current is flowing counterclockwise (from the magnet's POV) if we move the magnet towards the coil (and the circuit is closed, obviously).

However I'm not so sure about the direction of the induced voltage. Can you please explain to me that in Case 1) and Case 2) which end of the coil will be more positive, A or B?

[image]

Thanks for the explanation in advance!

Side note: This is a question I asked at  [Electrical Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622258/does-the-direction-of-coil-winding-impact-the-direction-of-induced-voltage), but nobody there could answer it, so I guess it is more related to Physics.

Comment: The direction of current flow in a circuit can be anything but the thing that matters a lot is the direction of current in a loop of solenoid which is always flxed if the velocity of the magnet is fixed (in terms of direction). Well that was a nice question.

Comment: An answer is difficult to write as the OP stated *I'm not so sure about the direction of the induced voltage* as it is not clear whether *induced potential difference* or *induced emf* which needs to be considered.

Comment: @Farcher The question asks about which end is more positive, this points to charge distribution, thus electric potential. But I agree this should be well distinguished from induced EMF in the answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification, I am not a physicist, so I cannot be as meticulous with the concepts as you guys are, but you are absolutely right I know. So I think inside the coil there is a non-conservative electric field, and therefore we cannot really define voltage and potential in its conventional way. So what would be the best term to use in such a case? Would induced EMF be appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already figured out in which direction the current flows.
In both cases the current produces an electromagnet whose north pole
is facing the north pole of the approaching bar magnet.
So both magnets repel each other, in accordance with [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law).

The fact that a current flows at all, implies a closed circuit.
Therefore I have drawn a resistor $R$ between the points A and B,
thus closing the circuit.
Then you can figure out the voltage by [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).

[image]

In case 1 the current flows through the resistor
from right right to left.
This gives you the voltage across the resistor:
positive on the right, negative on the left.

In case 2 the current flows through the resistor
from left to right.
This gives you the voltage across the resistor:
positive on the left, negative on the right.

Comment: A minor point is that a current will flow with no conductor between $A$ and $B$ as one could consider that $A$ and $B$ are the "plates" of a capacitor with a potential difference set up between the plates.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I meant the question. However, there is a tiny thing which disturbs me about it. The inductor equation is: V = L * di/dt . Here does NOT appear the direction of the coil winding. For example, imagine that we only know about point A and B, between them is an inductor but apart from that it is a black box. Now, imagine also that from a generator current is flowing in at point A and out at point B. That current will generate the same change in flux as the movement of the magnet. Does the direction of coil winding affect the direction of induced voltage in such a case too?

Comment: Because my concern is, that if it does, then we do absolutely not see it in the V = L * di/dt equation.

Comment: @gvg The formula $V=L\ di/dt$ applies to an inductor where the voltage is created by the coil's *own* magnetic field. But here the voltage is created by an *external* magnetic field (from the bar magnet). That is quite a different situation.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Okay, I'm pretty sure that you are right, but I don't see why. Imagine that from a generator current is flowing in at point A and flowing out at point B. Now, the change in magnetic flux is exactly the same like in the case of the moving bar magnet. And I thought that is all that matters, the change in the flux. So where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A variating magnetic flux through a coil creates a voltage in a concrete direction of rotation. I don't know from memory if the north pole makes it one way or the other, but the important thing is that it's always the same direction of rotation (given by Maxwell laws):
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times E = - \frac{dB}{dt}
\end{equation}

(In the picture you have, assuming the rotation direction is right, seems that the magnet generates a counter clock-wise current if you look at the coil from the magnet's perspective)

So obviously the current will flow towards the magnet or away from it depending on how you wind your coil! The only fixed thing is the direction of rotation of the current :)

Comment: Based on the given Maxwell equation you provided, I understand that if there is a change in the magnetic induction, then there will be a circular electric field. However I'm not so sure about it how I should conceptualize it in case of a coil. Imagine that I wind the coil like in Case 1). I take a digital multimeter and try to measure the voltage along the loops of the coil. I attach the common/gnd probe to point B and with the other probe I run along the loops towards point A. Would I see that the potential measured by the multimeter is rising as I'm getting closer and closer towards point A?

Comment: You would get a electric field that rotates whenever the flux changes, this is also known as Lenz's law in low undergrad level (Check wiki). But yeah the overall effect is that if you move the coil you change the flux (the magnetic field lines that passes inside the coil) and  that produces a rotating electric field depending on how quick it happens (if you move the coil super quick the magnetic field that pases through the coil will change quicker, also when the magnet is nearer the coil, the magnetic lines separate faster, so it also depens on the distance and the Modulus of B obviously) :)

Comment: Your explanation related to Lenz Law and the given Maxwell equation is clear for me, thank you for that! Could you please also answer my digital voltmeter question if you know the answer?

Comment: Sure men, but if you really understood what you said you didnthe answer to this question is obvious! Hehe. You create a rotating electric field that goes through the windings, and the potential (V) is the electric field integrated with distance (if it is constant in distance this results in a multiplication), so obviously the virtual potential you measure would increase as you approach A with the other probe, yeah :)

Comment: I'm a slow learner, but I would like to be sure, that's why I asked. Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: Np mate, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Consider Case 1) with a voltmeter (resistor) connected across terminals $A$ and $B$.
The current though the voltmeter will pass from terminal $A$ to terminal $B$.
For a resistor the current always passes from a point of high potential to a point of lower potential thus the potential of $A$ is higher than that of $B$ and the reading on the voltmeter would show that to be the case.

Your confusion might be due to the fact that the coil is a source of (induced) emf.
**Inside** a battery the current flows from the negative terminal to the positive terminal driven by the electrochemical reaction within the battery.
Within the coil it is the change of magnetic flux which is ultimately driving the current from terminal $B$ to terminal $A$ and that is the direction of the induced emf.

Comment: Yes, so if I understand your point correctly, in case of electromagnetic induction, the coil does always act like a battery/generator ?

Answer (score 1):

Winding direction does not affect the direction of the self induced emf of an inductor.
In the image shown below, an inductor coil is wound differently (fig(a) and fig(b)) and connected to a battery sending the current left to right. And the current is increasing (di/dt >0) to produce induction in the coil. Since Eind = - L (di/dt) and Eind must be in the opposite direction to E from the battery. It is the case in both situation, doesn't depend on the direction of the coil winding.
[image]

Comment: I think I understand Fig(a). But then in Fig(b), I think I understand that E shows from left to right and because of Lenz Law, Eind shows from right to left. But then I don't understand how do we get the direction of B and Bind in Fig(b) ?